# Import several microservice entities into gateway

Tags: jhipster

Is there a way to import in batch several microservices entities?
I have a microservice with entity A, B, and C
I am running in the gateway the command line

```
jhipster entity A
```

Them I reply to all question etc.
And I redo the same for entity B and C.

Is there a way to import all entities from ../icroservices/.jhipster/*.json ?
How to preset option in the import?

Comment: You can define your entities and apps in one JDL file rather than answering questions  see https://www.jhipster.tech/jdl/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From : https://www.jhipster.tech/creating-an-entity/

TIP: to regenerate all your entities at once, you can use the following commands (remove the `--force` to have questions asked when files have changed).

```
Linux & Mac: for f in `ls .jhipster`; do jhipster entity ${f%.*} --force ; done
Windows: for %f in (.jhipster/*) do jhipster entity %~nf --force
```

Answer (score 1):

Copy the .jhipster folder from the microservice project to the gateway project and then run the following command in the gateway project root:

```
jhipster --with-entities
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have {application}.jh file with entities, you can import it to gateway

```
jhipster import-jdl --ignore-application ../{msFolder}/{application}.jh
```

note, you should add ms declaration to {application}.jh file

```
microservice * with {msName}
```